# ¿Cómo navegar desde la pantalla de preferencias hacia otro fragmento?

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy creando una aplicación donde hay una pantalla de configuración que construí con la biblioteca de preferencias de Andreoid Jetpack. Quiero pasar de la pantalla de preferencias a un fragmento más detallado para personalizar el correo electrónico. Pero no sé cómo manejar el clic en la preferencia, he logrado importar el método provisto desde la biblioteca pero no sé cómo implementarlo ya que no hay información disponible. Tengo la función onPreferenceClick pero no sé cómo construir su lógica. Debería devolver falso cuando no se haga clic en él y verdadero cuando si se haga.

Este es mi código

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    if (onPreferenceClick(preferenceScreen.getPreference(1))) {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.editMailFragment)
    }

    override fun onPreferenceClick(preference: Preference?): Boolean {
    preference?.setOnPreferenceClickListener {

        }
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he resuelto, aquí está el código si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

```
val showValueListener = Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.editMailFragment)
        true
    }
findPreference<Preference>("email")?.onPreferenceClickListener = showValueListener
```

Comment: o simplemente `findPreference<Preference>("email")?.setOnPreferenceClickListener { findNavController().navigate(R.id.editMailFragment); true }`